# Average of a Calculated column in Solr

Tags: solr, solrcloud

I have a solr collection and I need some calculation done based on data. I have TotalLapTime and DrivingTime , completion rate for a driver is DrivingTime*100/TotalLapTime. I would like to find out average completion time for each team. How can I query the Solr for this ? I have been able only able to get sum of DrivingTime using stats. I am on Solr5

**Solr collection:**

```
    ID |DrivingTime|TotalLapTime| Team
    1  |   50    |    100       |  A
    2  |   25    |    100       |  A
    3  |   30    |    60        |  B
    4  |   50    |    60        |  B
    5  |   25    |    200       |  C
```

**Expected output:**

```
TEAM | AvgCompletionRate
  A  |      37%
  B  |      66.5%
  C  |      12.5%
```

Comment: A multi-level facet on team and then `avg(div(mul(DrivingTime,100),TotalLapTime))` could work, or even better, calculate the DT*100/TLT when indexing instead of doing it afterwards. It's static information for a document, calculate it when it gets indexed instead.

Comment: @MatsLindh Thank you ! If I do have completion rate pre calculated as completion_time. Would I be just doing stats.facet=Team&stats.field=completion_time and use the mean value ?

Comment: Or you can use the JSON Facet API with team as the first dimension and `avg(completion_time)` as the second. Both should work fine. An example is given in https://solr.apache.org/guide/solr/latest/query-guide/json-facet-api.html#sorting-facets-by-nested-functions

Comment: @MatsLindh Thank you ! Want to add as answer so I can accept ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First - one of the things with document based search indexes and analytics is that you should usually do as much pre-processing as possible, since your data *usually* is read once, then analyze in many different contexts. So in this case, adding `completion_time` as a separate field and calculate it when submitting the document to the index would be the best thing to do.

That makes it far easier to do any further analysis on the field, and we can then use the JSON Facet API to create buckets for each time, and then calculate the average completion time for those entries that fall into that bucket.

Adopted from [Solr's example for sorting facets by nested functions](https://solr.apache.org/guide/solr/latest/query-guide/json-facet-api.html#sorting-facets-by-nested-functions) example:

```
{
  "query": "*:*",
  "facet": {
    "categories":{
      "type": "terms",
      "field": "TEAM",
      "limit": 3,
      "sort": "avg_completion_time asc",
      "facet": {
        "avg_completion_time": "avg(completion_time)",
      }
    }
  }
}
```